# 3.6 Hair geometry nodes - ingrown hairs issue

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, hair

Before I begin, this issue doesnt happen with the hair particle system - so it has something to do with the quick fur geometry nodes setup. Normally this works fine with other meshes (like a plane, a sphere or suzanne)

[image: hair with the majority of it inside the mesh]

I'm using blender 3.6 and have imported a mesh from unreal engine (a metahuman) to do some modifications on it.

I want to add fur using the new geometry nodes system to the mesh so I have applied the 'Fur' (Shift + a -> Curve -> Fur) which acts as the quick start for the geometry node version.

Some hairs correctly stick out, but others grow into the mesh despite the face normals and orientation being correct. The issue seems to caused by the UV map itself but despite me creating a 2nd UV map and making sure nothing overlaps, the issue still remains.

[image: correct face orientation]
[image: correct normals]
[image: UV setup]

[image: Interpolate Hair curves modifier]

The image above is the view of the mesh when only the first two modifiers that are automatically generated (on creation of the fur) are active.
Note that I haven't made any changes to the geometry nodes setup so if you want to see that setup, you can just add the fur to any object in blender on your end.

- haurMap (the UV map seen above)
- face_fur = vertex group with only the skin of the face selected

I haven't found a similar question online about this so some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you changed the scale of the model or the Curves (fur) object? Is the scale applied (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) for both objects? Is there a *Surface Deform* GN modifier on the Curves object? Is it at the bottom of the stack? Are there any warnings/messages on this modifier? Have you tried to re-attach the hair in sculpt mode? (menu *Curves > Snap to Deformed Surface*)

Comment: I changed the scale after I imported it but I applied the scale before i added the fur so everything was set to scale = 1 (object and armature) in the screenshots above

I see what you mean about the surface deform - mine does have an error on it.
"Invalid surface UVs on 8325 curves". Ive tried to search for how to fix this but there's nothing in the blender docs or forums about it that help. In the interpolate hair curves geometry nodes setup i suspect the issue is within the node group labeled 'Sample Normals'.

(menu Curves > Snap to Deformed Surface) solved the issue though -thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

@Blunder's comment solved the issue with the (menu Curves > Snap to Deformed Surface) suggestion